# UINavigationController inside a UITabBarController with several views in the navigation controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I've got a `UINavigationController` that has a `UITableViewController` as it's root view.  The `UINavigationController` is inside a `UITabBarController`.

In the UITableViewController (*viewOne), if I click a cell a the following code runs

```
UIViewController *newView = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"newView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
[newView release];
```

Then, inside of newView is:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {

        NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController);

    }
    return self;
}
```

The logs have:

```
[8947:207] (null)
```

And if I try to push a new view controller to the navigationController, nothing happens.  Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.

In my application delegate, I've added a new property:

```
UINavigationController *profileNavigationController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *profileNavigationController;
```

And in IB, I've connected the profileNavigationController from the app delegate to Navigation Controller.

And now, when pushing new views, I call:

```
StartDateSelectorViewController *startDateSelectorViewController = [[StartDateSelectorViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StartDateSelectorView" bundle:nil];

Strength_EngineAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.profileNavigationController pushViewController:startDateSelectorViewController animated:YES ];
```